# SQL query for date stored as key-value pair

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with following structure

```
  **JobData**  - Table
---------------------------
    id   - Number    
    key   - Varchar
    value - Varchar



        Data:
    -----------------
    ID            value                key  
-----------------------------------------------   
    21212   2010-06-11T15:00:00      Job_End
    21213   2008-12-01T23:59:00     Job_Start
    21214   2008-12-01T23:59:00     Job_Start
    21215   2018-06-11T15:00:00     Job_End
    21216   2015-06-11T15:00:00     Job_End
```

If I want to retrieve records between two dates between 2000-06-01T:00:00, 2010-06-11T15:00:00, written the query as below.

```
SELECT * FROM  JobData jd
WHERE 
jd.key IN ('Job_Start', 'Job_End')
AND (jd.key = 'Job_Start' and jd.value BETWEEN '2000-06-01T:00:00' AND '2010-06-11T15:00:00')
AND (jd.key = 'Job_End' and jd.value BETWEEN '2000-06-01T:00:00' AND '2010-06-11T15:00:00')
```

But I am getting 0 records , please someone let me know where I am missing.

***Note:*** database is ORACLE

Thanks.

Comment: Your tags were right the first time. Your question is not about "relational database" or about "database administration".

Comment: Thank you for updating accordingly :)

Comment: I would suggest that a Key value store is the incorrect structure for this type of data.  A database refactoring will save you time and performance. and will almost certainly be worth it.

Comment: How do you know with this structure which job end goes with which job start?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect.

```
SELECT * FROM  JobData jd
WHERE 
jd.key IN ('Job_Start', 'Job_End')
AND (jd.key = 'Job_Start' and jd.value BETWEEN '2000-06-01T:00:00' AND '2010-06-11T15:00:00')
AND (jd.key = 'Job_End' and jd.value BETWEEN '2000-06-01T:00:00' AND '2010-06-11T15:00:00')
```

You should change it to

```
SELECT * FROM  JobData jd
WHERE 
jd.key IN ('Job_Start', 'Job_End')
AND (TO_DATE(jd.value,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN TO_DATE('2000-06-01T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2010-06-11T15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS'))
```

Comment: Still testing for `jd.value` to be simultaneously `'Job_Start'` and `'Job_End'`? Definite downvote.

Comment: still the query is not giving any result, i have swapped the column names correctly, sorry there was a typo.

Comment: @mathguy, Do you see the `IN` clause? It does not mean simultaneous 'Job_start' and 'Job_End'. Check your understanding of 'IN' clause.

Comment: You are treating the key column as string. It should be treated as DateTime column.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing, yes correct but apart from these key we have other key also which are not dates, so we have taken as varchar.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing I do see the IN clause. Do you see the other conditions, joined by AND? Do you understand what they mean?

Comment: @mathguy, I overlooked that. My mistake and fixed the answer.

Comment: You still have the mistake, from the original message, which I pointed out to Evaldas in a comment to his answer.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLiving, I have tried with TO_DATE using above query, getting "ORA-01821: date format not recognized  01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized" error.

Comment: @Raki, the value 01821. 00000 is not in the date format specified. That is a correct message. You need to fix the values if you are sure the key column is DateTime else leave it as string.

Comment: I have given like this: SELECT * FROM JobData jd
WHERE (TO_DATE(jd.value,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN TO_DATE('2008-12-01T23:59:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS')
AND TO_DATE('2018-06-11T15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS'))
and jb.key IN('Job_Start', 'Job_End') , is there anything wrong in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's not going to work, because you're asking for a value to be both `Job_Start` and `Job_End` at the same time. If you really want to return all records between `2000-06-01T:00:00` and `2010-06-11T15:00:00`, then this should be correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM JobData jd
WHERE jd.key IN ('Job_Start', 'Job_End')
  AND jd.value BETWEEN '2000-06-01T00:00:00' AND '2010-06-11T15:00:00'
```

Comment: And don't forget the mistake in the date string: the first one has `T:00:00`, that should be `T00:00:00`.

Comment: Please note the observation in S. Bohara's comment to his answer, too - you have jd.value and jd.key mixed up.

Comment: @mathguy Oh god, I changed that intentionally looking at OPs question first of all. I'll swap it back